TikZ pictures for differential geometry
This is not a question in the strict sense of the word, but an invitation to other members of the community to contribute here  their own creation on the subject "pictures for differential geometry". It is also a tiny return to the enormous contribution of the community members.
So here is my TikZ-picture:

and here is the TikZ-code:
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

    \begin{document}    
   \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8,>=stealth]
    \begin{axis}[colormap/blackwhite,
        view={30}{60},axis lines=none] 
        \addplot3[surf,samples=60, point meta=x+3*z*z-0.25*y,
        domain=0:2*pi,y domain=0:2*pi,z buffer=sort]
        ({(2.0+1.0*cos(deg(x))-0.5*sin(deg(x)))*cos(deg(y))}, 
        {(6+cos(deg(x))+1.5*sin(deg(x)))*sin(deg(y))}, 
        {1.5*sin(deg(x))});
    \end{axis}
    \begin{scope}[->,line width=0.6pt,>=stealth,color=black!50,opacity=0.8]
        \draw (-1.5,-2.5) to (3,-2.5)  ;
        \draw (-0.5,-3.5) to  (-0.5,0.5)  ;
        \draw (6,-2.5) to (11,-2.5)  ;
        \draw (7.3,-3.5) to  (7.3,0.5)  ;
    \end{scope}
    \draw [line width=1.0pt, dashed, fill=black!70,opacity=0.3,fill opacity=0.6, samples=100] plot [smooth cycle] coordinates {  (4,2)  (4.8,3.3) (5.6,2.8)(5.3, 1.7)};
    \draw [line width=1.0pt, dashed, fill=black!70,opacity=0.3,fill opacity=0.6, samples=100] plot [smooth cycle] coordinates {  (3.3,1.5)  (3.8,2.6) (4.9,2.5)(4.65, 1.5)};
    \draw [line width=1.0pt, dashed, fill=black!70,opacity=0.3,fill opacity=0.6, samples=100] plot [smooth cycle] coordinates {  (7,-1.5)  (8.0,0)  (9.6,-1) (9.0,-2.8) (8.3, -2.5)};
    \draw [line width=1.0pt, dashed, fill=black!70,opacity=0.3,fill opacity=0.6, samples=100] plot [smooth cycle] coordinates {  (7,-1.5)  (7.8,-0.2)  (8.1, -2.2)};
    \draw [line width=1.0pt, dashed, fill=black!70,opacity=0.3,fill opacity=0.6, samples=100] plot [smooth cycle] coordinates {  (-1,-1.8)  (0.0,-0.5)  (2.2,-1.5) (1.5,-2.2) (0.8, -3.1)};
    \draw [line width=1.0pt, dashed, fill=black!70,opacity=0.3,fill opacity=0.6, samples=100] plot [smooth cycle] coordinates {  (0.6,-2.0)  (0.2,-0.55)  (2.2, -1.5)}; 
    \draw[->,line width=1.0pt] (4,1.65)  to [bend right=15] node[midway,left] {\small$\varphi$}  (1.35,-0.9);
    \draw[->,line width=1.0pt] (5.2,2.5)  to [bend left=15] node[midway,right] {\small$\psi$}  (8,0.1);
    \draw[->,line width=1.0pt] (1.7,-1)  to [bend left=15] node[midway,below] {\small$\psi\circ\varphi^{-1}$}  (7.1,-0.8);
    \begin{small}
        \draw [color=black](-0.3,-1.7) node {$\varphi(U)$};
        \draw [color=black](8.8,-1.4) node {$\psi(V)$};
        \draw [color=black](3.7,1.8) node {$U$};
        \draw [color=black](5.1,2.8) node {$V$};
        \draw [color=black](2.3,3.6) node {$M$};
        \draw [color=black](-1.,-3.0) node {$\mathbb{R}^n$};    
        \draw [color=black](6.8,-3.0) node {$\mathbb{R}^n$};
    \end{small}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


This seems rather specialised?

I don't think this is a question. These kinds of examples better belong on sites like https://texample.net/tikz/examples/ and not scattered in TeX.SE.

@WillieWong  I think I've declare clearly enough the intention of my post. As I wrote, it's mainly "an invitation to other members of the community to contribute here their own creation on the subject", something which asks a "response" from other members.

yes, you stated it pretty clearly, but I don't think what you want is in the spirit of StackExchange sites. https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask
